# Multiple row span in HTML data

Tags: html

I am trying to create a table similar to the one shown in the attached screenshot. Data for this table is coming through the python script, but I need some inputs on HTML side on how to create a table that can span through multiple rows

With my little knowledge on HTML, I tried creating the table with the following code, but it doesn't appear like its working as expected. It would be highly helpful if anyone can throw some light on what could be wrong here

```css
table,
td,
th {
  font-family: Verdana;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

th,
tr {
  height: 50px;
}

td {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 15pt;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: lightgreen
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Project</th>
      <th>Environment</th>
      <th>Data1</th>
      <th>Multiple Data</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">project1</td>
      <td rowspan="4">prod</td>
      <td rowspan="4">project1data</td>
      <td rowspan="4">project1 multi row data1</td>
      <td rowspan="4">project1 multi row data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">project2</td>
      <td rowspan="4">stage</td>
      <td rowspan="4">project2data</td>
      <td rowspan="4">project2 multi row data1</td>
      <td rowspan="4">project2 multi row data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">project3</td>
      <td rowspan="4">test</td>
      <td rowspan="4">project3data</td>
      <td rowspan="4">project3 multi row data1</td>
      <td rowspan="4">project3 multi row data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">project4</td>
      <td rowspan="4">dev</td>
      <td rowspan="4">project4data</td>
      <td rowspan="4">project4 multi row data1</td>
      <td rowspan="4">project4 multi row data2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4">project5</td>
      <td rowspan="4">qa</td>
      <td rowspan="4">project5data</td>
      <td rowspan="4">project5 multi row data1</td>
      <td rowspan="4">project5 multi row data2</td>
    </tr>

  </table>
```

[image]

Comment: I created a snippet for you and moved the inline CSS to the style pane. Also you had multiple html and body tags. I also removed `<table id="status_report" width="100%"> since a table cannot be a child of a table. It looks like you are missing some colspans

Comment: You can also check this example, https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_span

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The mistake is that you have `rowspan="4"` even in the last `td`. You will need to avoid a `rowspan` there:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Project</th>
    <th>Environment</th>
    <th>Data1</th>
    <th>Multiple Data</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">project1</td>
    <td rowspan="3">prod</td>
    <td rowspan="3">project1data</td>
    <td>project1 multi row data1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>project1 multi row data2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>project1 multi row data3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">project2</td>
    <td rowspan="3">stage</td>
    <td rowspan="3">project2data</td>
    <td>project2 multi row data1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>project2 multi row data2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>project2 multi row data3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">project3</td>
    <td rowspan="3">test</td>
    <td rowspan="3">project3data</td>
    <td>project3 multi row data1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>project3 multi row data2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>project3 multi row data3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">project4</td>
    <td rowspan="3">dev</td>
    <td rowspan="3">project4data</td>
    <td>project4 multi row data1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>project4 multi row data2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>project4 multi row data3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">project5</td>
    <td rowspan="3">qa</td>
    <td rowspan="3">project5data</td>
    <td>project5 multi row data1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>project5 multi row data2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>project5 multi row data3</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: This is so far the cleanest solution

Comment: Thanks, I used this solution and it was pretty straight forward.

Comment: @user6930 you are welcome. You can accept this answer then to help future visitors find the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Please check this :

Basically you can use simple `<div>` inside the td to accomplish this for 3rd table column.

https://jsfiddle.net/ryb0w54a/

```css
table { border:1px solid #000;border-collapse:collapse;}
th {border:1px solid #000;}
td { border:1px solid #000;}
div { border-bottom : 1px solid #000}
div.last { border-bottom : 0;}
```

```html
<table>
<th>Project</th>
<th>Environment</th>
<th>Data1</th>
<th>Multiple Data</th>
<tr>
 <td>Project 1</td>
 <td>Env 1</td>
 <td>Project 1 Data</td>
 <td>
  <div>project1 multi row data1</div>
  <div>project1 multi row data2</div>
  <div class="last">project1 multi row data3</div>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Project 1</td>
 <td>Env 1</td>
 <td>Project 1 Data</td>
 <td>
  <div>project1 multi row data1</div>
  <div>project1 multi row data2</div>
  <div class="last">project1 multi row data3</div>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I like the last bottom border!

Answer (score 1):

remove `rowspan=4` for your multiple data column and add them to another `<tr>` with `rowspan=1` after relative no. of empty divs.

Comment: If you want to earn REP, please click the `<>` and add a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you what you require

```css
table,
td,
th {
  font-family: Verdana;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

th,
tr {
  height: 50px;
}

td {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 15pt;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: lightgreen
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Project</th>
    <th>Environment</th>
    <th>Data</th>
    <th>Multiple Data</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>A1</td>
    <td>A2</td>
    <td>A3</td>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>B1</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>B2</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach was correct but the way you implemented it has a small mistake. I think this code will give you the proper way to address your problem. The code is pretty basic but will help you to understand how it works.

```html
 <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Head 1</th>
                <th>Head 2</th>
                <th>Head 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="4">Data 1</td>
                <td rowspan="4">Data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 2.1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 2.1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Data 2.1</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this simply **without using rowspan** and just adding another **table in the last td** where the multiple rows will come.

> Here we go :

```css
table,
td,
th {
  font-family: Verdana;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

th,
tr {
  height: 50px;
}

td {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 15pt;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-color: lightgreen
}

table tr td table {
  border: none;
}

table tr td table td {
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

table tr td table tr:first-child td {
  border-top: none;
}

table tr td table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Project</th>
    <th>Environment</th>
    <th>Data1</th>
    <th>Multiple Data</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>project1</td>
    <td>prod</td>
    <td>project1data</td>

    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>project1 multi row data2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>project1 multi row data2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>project1 multi row data2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>project1 multi row data2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>project2</td>
    <td>prod</td>
    <td>project1data</td>

    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>project1 multi row data2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>project1 multi row data2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>project1 multi row data2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>project1 multi row data2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>project3</td>
    <td>prod</td>
    <td>project1data</td>

    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>project1 multi row data2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>project1 multi row data2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>project1 multi row data2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>project1 multi row data2</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: @MihirBhende no problem :P Some moderator rejected your edit suggestion